# What is the benefit of deploying AWS WAF in CloudFront instead of AWS load balancer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ddos, web-application-firewall

What is the benefit of deploying AWS WAF in CloudFront instead of AWS load balancer? I've read that the CloudFront is able to absorb lots of traffic volume (volumetric DDoS), but at the same time the AWS load balancers can automatically scale up and I couldn't find any information about the limits in terms of connection or packets per seconds so the attacker should not be able to saturate the load balancer resources (volumetric DDoS should be automatically absorbed by AWS as well).

Answer (score 0):

***tl;dr** - It's a traffic funnel.  Get rid of the large amounts of bad with DDoS, get rid of more targeted app-specific attacks at WAF, then LB only good traffic for the servers at the end.*

While they perform completely separate services, they're two parts of a whole for successful app performance.

A load balancer is going to route traffic to n+1 web/application servers for whatever IP/Port you specify. But it will route ALL of it, there is some conditional logic in advanced LB systems but it's not acting as a security device. It's going to send whatever it receives to the server based on your load balancing method (round robin, least connection...).

Having one or more volumetric security services, like DDoS and Anti-Fraud/Bot and **then** a WAF allows you to do a negative security postures first (DDoS), filtering bad traffic at volume.  The WAF would follow second doing signature-based and/or application-specific payload inspection to ensure only valid and safe traffic is hitting your apps. This would be a positive security posture similar to an ACL-allow list.  DDoS validates for bad traffic and drops, WAF would validate against good traffic and allow it through.

This type of funnel of DDoS => WAF => LB does two key things, drops the largest amount malicious traffic first, then can do more costly payload inspection second (cost in both price and performance), then load balance legitimate traffic third.

For example, if you usually average 20Gbps of traffic per day and suddenly a DDoS attack hits your public IP at 300Gbps (relatively small) you don't want that traffic coming into your app ingress and charging you for ingress, then ALB LCU hours before being dropped. You're just paying more for the same amount of valid users.

Let's also not forget the performance hit to your application will be very noticeable if it had to go through all that plumbing before being dropped.

This is an over-simplistic answer, I know but it should answer the immediate question, but if you have more follow up q's let me know.